# C++ shared DB between 2 classes

Tags: c++, database, vector, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

my problem is the following: I have 2 classes which both contain vector of data, the vector length and the data struct is very big and almost 90% of the data is sam between the 2 classes. Current implementation is that each class holds its own vector of data thus there is big memory consumption.

My goal is to optimize the memory and create some kind of DB where it will hold the data, and the classes will hold some kind of reference to the DB.

Guidelines:

1. Each class can manipulate its vector of data and it needs to reflect on the DB, means that for example both classes hold a ref to the same data struct and one of the classes removes it from its vector, the DB still need to hold the data for the second class.
2. if no class hold ref to data, the data needs to be deleted from DB.
3. if both classes hold the same data, I don't want replication.

My design was to use some kind of a hash map where the classes will hold key to the map, and the hash map itself will hold a reference count, but than I thought about smart pointers in C++.

This is the code for my design but I am not sure regarding my implementation:

```
class Data {
public:
    Data(const int xTemp, const int yTemp, const int idTemp) {
        x = xTemp;
        y = yTemp;
        id = idTemp;
    }

    int getX() { return x; }
    int getY() { return y; }
    int getId() { return id; }

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int id;
};

class ModelA {
public:
    ModelA() {
        vector.clear();
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::tuple<int /*key to DB */, std::shared_ptr<Data> /* ptr to data */, std::string /* id Type per Model */> > vector;
};

class ModelB {
    ModelB() {
        vector.clear();
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::tuple<int /*key to DB */, std::shared_ptr<Data> /* ptr to data */, std::string /* id Type per Model */> > vector;
};

std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<Data> > db;
```

Basically we can insert elements to modelA and modelB and we don't want to have same memory if the data is the same(based on id).

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: What you are doing can work.

Comment: `shared_ptr` would have significant overhead, since now you need a separate heap allocation for each piece of `Data`, plus the control block used by `shared_ptr` itself. If `Data` is as small as you show, I predict that having each model store its own copy with no attempt at sharing would still consume less memory than sharing via the proposed scheme; `std::shared_ptr<Data>` would ultimately require more memory than two copies of `Data`. That's before accounting for `std::unordered_map` nodes, which is yet another memory allocation.

Comment: In the scheme you propose, if both `ModelA` and `ModelB` remove an entry with a given key, it's not clear by what mechanism this key would get removed from `db`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the data is much bigger, its like 1k of bytes its just an example

Comment: @drescherjm what is the mechanism that I need to use in order to implement it via shared pointers?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that is my question, how the DB should behave it case class a and class b add the same key, or remove the same key

Answer (score 1):

You could make your scheme work along these lines:

```
class Database {
  std::unordered_map<int, std::weak_ptr<Data> > db;
public:
  std::shared_ptr<Data> add(int key, const Data& val) {
    std::weak_ptr<Data>& wp = db[key];
    std::shared_ptr<Data> ret = wp.lock();
    if (!ret) {
      ret = std::make_shared<Data>(val);
      wp = ret;
    }
    return ret;
  }

  // Must be called **after** disposing of your copy of
  // the `shared_ptr<Data>`
  void remove(int key) {
    if (db[key].expired()) {
      // No more references.
      db.erase(key);
    }
  }
};
```

---

Upon further thought, `remove` could be called automatically by a deleter. Something like this (not tested):

```
class Database {
  std::unordered_map<int, std::weak_ptr<Data> > db;

  struct Deleter {
    Database* db;
    int key;
    void operator()(const Data* ptr) {
      db->remove(key);
      delete ptr;
    }
  };
public:
  std::shared_ptr<Data> add(int key, const Data& val) {
    std::weak_ptr<Data>& wp = db[key];
    std::shared_ptr<Data> ret = wp.lock();
    if (!ret) {
      ret = std::shared_ptr<Data>(
          new Data(val), Deleter{this, key});
      wp = ret;
    }
    return ret;
  }

private:    
  void remove(int key) {
    assert(db[key].expired());
    db.erase(key);
  }
};
```

You lose the optimization of `make_shared` that uses a single allocation for the object and the control block. Now two heap allocations per `Data` instance are performed.

Comment: That is a great option, the only one thing that I miss is is it possible to call remove automatically? for example after modelA vector deletes one data from its vector it will call the remove function automatically, in the destructor or something like that ?

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution based on a deleter that would remove the entry automatically when the last reference is released.

Comment: I wouldn't access it as `std::shared_ptr<Data> add(int, Data)`, but `data_ptr get(int)` (or even `operator[]`) If I were to have an `add`, it'd take by `std::shared_ptr<Data>`

Comment: @Caleth Without an `add`, how would `db` ever become non-empty? Where would entries come from? With `add` that takes `shared_ptr`, you won't be able to stash a custom deleter into the control block and won't be automatically notified when the last reference is gone. For deleter-based solution, there has to be a factory in there somewhere.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `get` would default-construct them.

Comment: @Caleth Well, `Data` as shown doesn't have a default constructor. Anyway, I assume the OP would be able to adapt the solution to their needs.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the help, do you know what is the cost in memory than? 16 bytes instead of 8 bytes?Also, are you familiar with a way when ModelA.vector.emplace_back will be called than the add function of the DB will be called automatically ?

Comment: The `shared_ptr` you place in the vector must come from `Database::add` or a similar factory function, or else it won't have the right deleter. You can write another class to manage the vector, that would cooperate with `Database`, and have models use that class.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, I am just trying to think how I can hide the db.add function inside the model or data class in order for the emplace_back function to work implicitly. @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Like I said, you could probably implement a class wrapping your `std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::shared_ptr<Data>>>`, and have models use that, instead of storing the vector directly. That class would then talk to `Database` in its emplace implementation.